# Consecutive and sequence insert in node.js sqlite

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sqlite, event-handling

my code is:

```
 var json = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
 async.forEach(json, function (that, callback) {
      sqlitedb.run("INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ("+that+")" , function () {
           console.log(that); callback();
      });
 });
```

The callback() placed on after insert item. but when i execute, my json items inserted on no squence and result is like:

```
7
8
9
4
5
3
6
1
2
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Note that queries without an `ORDER BY` clause aren't guaranteed to have any particular ordering anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use async.eachSeries:

forEach will execute in parallel.

```
async.eachSeries(json, function (that, callback) {
      sqlitedb.run("INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ("+that+")" , function () {
           console.log(that); callback();
      });
 });
```